# What is the Use of setting Interval for checkpoint in spark streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

**1)I want to know about the use of check point interval ???

2)is there any relationship checkpoint interval with window size or sliding interval or batch interval ????

3)while running spark streaming in standalone cluster  mode ,task(or work) is distributed to worker nodes by the master???

Here i am performing streaming operation ,by reading  list of files from my file system  always reading files task is done by only one worker it is not shared to all the workers ???(currently i have two workers )

Thanks for your help>>!**

Comment: Is there something wrong with your keyboard? There seem to be random characters all over your post...

Comment: please ask 1 question at the time.

Comment: I believe all questions are answered here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: am not able to understand about checkpoint interval if we have window like windowsize 4 mints,sliding interval 1 minute........

Answer (score 1):

1,2) Check point interval is generally about 5-7 times the data set interval time. This is considered good.
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/

3) Yes